VMWare Network Issue
I am having a strange issue on VMWare Workstation Pro. I have two VMs, Kali and Ubuntu. I gave both a static IP (this was the assignment), set them to the same network adapter (custom - vmnet8), and set the network adapter to the the same IP scheme.

vmnet8 is set to "Host-only"
DHCP is off
The network IP scheme is 192.168.10.0/24
Kali is at 192.168.10.2/24
Ubuntu is at 192.168.10.3/24

Both VMs are able to ping the gateway (my host computer) at 192.168.10.1 without any issues.
What is strange is, Kali is not able to ping Ubuntu UNTIL Ubuntu pings Kali. So, I start both VMs, I try to ping Ubuntu from Kali with ping 192.168.10.3 and receive no answers. Then I will ping Kali from Ubuntu with ping 192.168.10.2 and Kali will respond. Then all of a sudden the Kali VM starts getting responses from Ubuntu.
Any ideas what could be causing the issue?

Any ideas what could be causing the issue stateful packet filtering (firewall) has been deployed on the Ubuntu host.

I can't seem to reproduce it on my system (Arch so really recent kernel) anymore though. I mean, I do have memories of bumping into similar behavior in the past, but apparently it has been fixed, as in, netfilter now differentiates echo request and echo reply when perform stateful filtering...(?) (Also, it shouldn't happen if all icmp messages are "statelessly" accepted. Maybe add the output of iptables-save and nft list ruleset from the Ubuntu host to your post.)

@John I switched to NAT and am receiving the same results

@TomYan I don't have any nft rules or iptables rules on right now. iptables --list shows no entries in any tables and nft list ruleset does not output anything

Appreciate all the help guys! I still have no clue what the issue is. Kali pings only reach Ubuntu immediately after I ping Kali from Ubuntu. If I boot both machines and try to ping Ubuntu first, no luck

Both VMs are able to ping the gateway (my host computer) at 192.168.10.1 What about ping'ing VMs (well the Ubuntu one in particular) from the gateway? Maybe you can check ip neigh on Kali when the ping doesn't work, and/or tcpdump (for ARP and/or ICMP messages) on Ubuntu before you starting ping'ing from Kali. If you stop ping'ing from Ubuntu, will it stop sending replies for the pings from Kali?

Hey guys appreciate all the help - what I ended up doing that fixed it was just putting Kali and Ubuntu on a LAN Segment. I didn't even know that was a thing on VMWare before this whole problem. I just took the gateways out of the static IP config files and was able to ping between computers immediately.
